# I'm having trouble initializing a MATLAB class

Tags: matlab, class, oop, object, initialization

I'm new to object-oriented programming with MATLAB and I'm having trouble initializing a class I'm building. I'm building a neural network from scratch, and I'm using the following class called network with an initialization function called layers:

```
classdef network

properties
    sizes
    biases
    weights
    nLayers
end

methods
    function [ ] = layers(self)
        self.nLayers = length(self.sizes);
        self.biases{1} = zeros(self.sizes(1));
        for i = 2:self.nLayers
            self.biases{i} = zeros(self.sizes(i), 1);
            for j = 1:self.sizes(i)
                bias(j, 1) = normRand(0);
            end
            self.biases{i} = bias(1:j, 1);
        end
        for i = 2:self.nLayers
            for j = 1:self.sizes(i)
                 for k = 1:self.sizes(i-1)
                     weight(j, k) = normRand(0);
                 end
            end
            self.weights{i} = weight(1:j, 1:k);
        end
    end
```

So after I create a variable net of class network and set the sizes as below:

```
>> net = network; net.sizes = [2 3 2 4]

net = 

  network with properties:

  sizes: [2 3 2 4]
 biases: []
weights: []
nLayers: []
```

I run the layers function, but nothing updates.

```
>> net.layers
>> net

net = 

  network with properties:

  sizes: [2 3 2 4]
 biases: []
weights: []
nLayers: []
```

What's confusing to me is that if I set a break point at the end of the layers function, I get these results in debugging mode:

```
>> net.layers
29          end
K>> self

self = 

  network with properties:

  sizes: [2 3 2 4]
 biases: {[2×2 double]  [3×1 double]  [2×1 double]  [4×1 double]}
weights: {[]  [3×2 double]  [2×3 double]  [4×2 double]}
nLayers: 4
```

Which is the result I'm looking for. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? Also, does anyone know of a way to pass an input to a class so that I could create my network like:
    net = network(sizes)
?

Also, I understand that python is much better for neural networks and that even java would be a better alternative. I'm doing this as a learning exercise and am not really interested in anyone's opinion on which language is best for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab has two types of classes - value classes and handle classes. By default, Matlab's classes are value classes, which means that Matlab operates on a copy of the object, rather than a reference to it.  In the example, the `layers` method is operating on a copy of the object and the `net` object is not updated as you observed.

This article explains the differences in detail:
 https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html

There are two solutions to the problem:

1) Keep using a value class and return the modified object from the `layers` function

```
function self = layers(self)
```

Then use assignment to update the object.

```
net = net.layers
```

2) Use a handle class by deriving `network` from the handle class.

```
classdef network < handle
```

The `layers` function will now modify a reference to the object.

The link below contains more information on object modification in Matlab.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/matlab-vs-other-oo-languages.html#bslvcv1

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the modified `self` object from the `layers` method:

```
function self = layers(self)
  ...
```

This is because classes in MATLAB are [*value* classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) by default (i.e. methods that modify the object must return the modified object as an output argument). Alternatively, you can also design your class with reference-like behavior by making it a [*handle* class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-objects.html). Some useful examples of value and handle classes can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/which-kind-of-class-to-use.html), along with guidelines for when to use them.

In addition, you can create a [constructor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html) for your class object, which can take a set of inputs to initialize it with. For example, it could be designed like so:

```
function self = network(sizes, biases, weights, nLayers)
  if (nargin > 0)
    self.sizes = sizes;
  end
  if (nargin > 1)
    self.biases = biases;
  end
  if (nargin > 2)
    self.weights = weights;
  end
  if (nargin > 3)
    self.nLayers = nLayers;
  end
end
```

You could then instantiate it like so:

```
net = network([2 3 2 4]);  % Sets sizes to [2 3 2 4] and other properties to []
```